# magento 1.9x Add attribute in Inventory tab?

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is the setup script to add attribute to General tab, but how to add it into Inventory tab instead?

```
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$attributeSetDefault = 'Default';
$attributeGroup = 'General';
$attributeSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attributeSetDefault);
if ($attributeSetId) {
    $attributeGroupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeGroup);
}

// Attribut : Barcode EAN13
$attributCode = 'localisation';

$attribute = $installer->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributCode);
if (empty($attribute['attribute_id'])) {

    $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributCode, array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        'backend' => '',
        //'input_renderer' => 'PointOfSales/adminhtml_product_helper_form_barcodeean13', //definition of renderer
        'label' => 'Localisation',
        'class' => '',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => 'simple',
        'configurable' => false,
    ));

    $attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attributCode);

    if ($attributeGroupId && $attributeId) {
        $installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, $attributeId);
    }
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Did you add attribute on Inventory tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the attribute in inventory group in this way.

You can check the below file for more clarification:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml

and

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml

You can add your attribute by customising this file according to your requirement.

Comment: How would you amend these to add the programmatically created attribute?